# Use reflection to create lambda expression like x => new { .. }

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, expression

I have an `IQuerable<object> source` object and have to get from it something like that (but using reflection).

```
source.Select(t => new SelectListItem { Name = t.Name, Value = t.Id })
```

How can I do that, or where can i find references of constructing that kind of expression tree.

Thanks

Comment: if you know the type you may use Enumerable.Cast: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx

Comment: Would it be an option to cast the elements to `dynamic`?

Comment: dynamic sounds a better option than reflection. It look quite awkward to use reflection. Wy can't you use something that conform to an interface like INameValuePair?

Comment: Well, i am afraid a dynamic expression cannot be used in an expression tree.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create `Expression`s using the `System.Linq.Expressions` namespace ( [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb506649.aspx) )

In your case, it would look something like this:

```
var source = typeof( Source );
var target = typeof( SelectListItem );

var t = Expression.Parameter( source, "t" );

var sourceName = Expression.MakeMemberAccess( t, source.GetProperty( "Name" ) );
var sourceId = Expression.MakeMemberAccess( t, source.GetProperty( "Id" ) );

var assignName = Expression.Bind( target.GetProperty( "Name" ), sourceName );
var assignValue = Expression.Bind( target.GetProperty( "Value" ), sourceId );
var targetNew = Expression.New( target );
var init = Expression.MemberInit( targetNew, assignName, assignValue );

var lambda =
  ( Expression<Func<Source,SelectListItem>> ) Expression.Lambda( init, t );
```

The you could use it like this:

```
IQueryable<Source> list = ...

List<SelectListItem> items = list.Select( lambda ).ToList();
```

Comment: Is there any way to change `var lambda = (Expression<Func<Source, SelectListItem>>)` to `var lambda = ( Expression<Func<Source, object>>)`?

Answer (score 0):

Its a little unclear as to what Type information (if any) is known during runtime. Piggybacking on **Nicholas Butler's** answer (since its been accepted) Let's assume that you will "know" the source type (i.e. what is the Type of T in the IQueryable source) and you will "know" the target Type (item Type returned from the IQueryable.Select extension method). When I say "know", I mean it is something that can be discovered at runtime without dynamics, reflection, late-binding, etc. Otherwise his solution will only work if the source and target types just happen to have properties with those matching names (i.e. "Name/Id" & "Name/Value").

Given this, there is a pretty simple solution without having to manually construct your lambda expression...

Solution: 
First lets define these 2 types just so we know what we are dealing with. I only do this because I do not know what types you are using, so these are really **placeholders** for what you are actually using, so this is not needed for your solution, just for demo/example purposes:

```
//this is whatever your source item type is (t) 
public class NameIdPair
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }
}

//this is whatever the SelectListItem type is you're using
public class SelectListItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Next lets define a simple static class with 2 methods. One method will create the lambda expression and the other method will convert and select the source (IQueryable) into IEnumerable:

```
 public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TItem> Select<TSource, TItem>(this IQueryable<TSource> source)
        where TSource : NameIdPair
        where TItem : SelectListItem, new()
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

        return source.Select(CreateLambda<TSource, TItem>());
    }

    public static Expression<Func<TSource, TItem>> CreateLambda<TSource, TItem>()
        where TSource : NameIdPair
        where TItem : SelectListItem, new()
    {

        return (t) => new TItem { Name = t.Name, Value = t.Id };
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    //create an instance of an IQueryable<T> for demo purposes
var source = new[]
{
    new NameIdPair {Name = "test1_name", Id = "test1_Id"},
    new NameIdPair {Name = "test2_name", Id = "test2_Id"}
}.AsQueryable();

//you can call the "Select" extension method to select the queryable into an enum.
var enumerable = source.Select<NameIdPair, SelectListItem>();   
//'enumerable' is an IEnumerable<SelectListItem> instance

//or if you just want the lambda expression...
var lambda = QueryableExtensions.CreateLambda<NameIdPair, SelectListItem>();

//lambda.ToString() returns "t => new SelectListItem() {Name = t.Name, Value = t.Id}";
```

So there you go. Not sure if that's is what you are looking for, or if it fits your needs. Hopefully someone will find it useful.